# Retrieving struct from array of struct in C for qsort

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to retrieve two values from structs in array of struct, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need this for **qsort**.

Here is an example of my code:

```
typedef struct test {
    int data1;
    int data2;
} *test;
```

Then I make a array of struct and return a pointer to the array:

```
test* foo(**some args**)
    test* array = malloc(sizeof(proc));
    int currentElement = 0;
    while(...){
        // get some data
        // and make space for struct
        array[currentElement] = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
        // add data to struct
        array[currentElement] -> data1 = ...;
        array[currentElement] -> data2 = ...;
        // resize array for the next wave of structs
        array = realloc(array, (currentElement + 1) * sizeof(struct proces));
        currentElement++;
    }
    return array
```

When I try to access and print the struct in array it works (numberOfElement is a global variable):

```
void printData(test* a) {
    printf("%s\n", "Data");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        printf("%5d\n",
                a[i]->data1
                );
    }
}
```

But if I try to write a comperator function for **qsort**, it gives me an error (request for member ‘data1’ in something not a structure or union):

```
int comp (test* first, test* second){
    return first->data1 - second->data1;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Add function foo that return pointer to the struct array. **Thank you dasblinkenlight!**

I have another problem:

This works!

```
int comp (void *a, void* b){
    test* first = (test*)a;
    test* second = (test*)b;
    return (*first)->data1 - (*second)->data1;
}
```

When i try to sort the array like this:

```
test* a = foo(...);
qsort(a, numberOfElements, sizeof(test), comp);
printData(a);
```

It gives me an error:

```
warning: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from Naloga2.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:765:13: note: expected ‘__compar_fn_t’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(void *, void *)’
 extern void qsort (void *__base, size_t __nmemb, size_t __size,
```

---

**EDIT 2**: Final solution

```
int comp (const void *a, const void* b){
        test* first = (test*)a;
        test* second = (test*)b;
        return (*first)->data1 - (*second)->data1;
    }
```

Comment: (1)remove typedef (2) send struct test* as parameter and change varray to struct test* and check. it might resolve the issue.

Comment: Error: passing argument 4 of ‘qsort’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
Could you please past an example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `typedef` defines `test` as a pointer type, not a plain type. Then `test*` becomes a double-pointer, i.e. `struct test**`. When you write `first->data1`, you are applying `->` operator to a pointer to pointer to `struct test`, which is not a pointer to a `struct`.

Since `test*` is a double-pointer, you need to rewrite your `comp` to dereference it once before obtaining a member, as follows:

```
int comp (const void *a, const void* b){
    const test* first = (const test*)a;
    const test* second = (const test*)b;
    return (*first)->data1 - (*second)->data1;
}
```

You need to pass `void*` and cast to `test*` internally, because `qsort` expects a function pointer that takes a pair of constant `void` pointers; simply casting a function pointer will compile and might even work, but the behavior would be undefined.

Comment: This works, thank you. But now I have another problem, look at the edit.

Comment: @Theory I forgot to add `const`. The edit should fix the warning.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct test *test;
```

This can also be written as

```
typedef struct test* test;
```

So now test is already a pointer. So when you write

```
test *first;
```

It becomes

```
struct test **first;
```

You should be having something like

```
typedef struct test test;
```

Then

```
test *first ;
```

will have `first` as a pointer to your structure.

This makes sure that the parameter `comp()` is expecting is a single pointer and also the access holds good.

```
first->data1
```